# wireless card not working via command line ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless, atheros

So, i set my /etc/network/interfaces file like this:

```
### START INTERFACE: wlp5s0 on BOOT
auto wlp5s0

#home
iface wlp5s0 inet dhcp
    wireless-essid <my-ssid-here->
    wireless-psk <my-pass-here->
```

if i reboot my computer, and run: `ip a` i get

```
4: wlp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 24:ec:99:59:5d:8a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

then i run `iwconfig` i get:

```
wlp5s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"<<ssid-entered-about-in-config-here>>"  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

if i run: `rfkill unblock all` then `iwlist scan` I get:

```
Scan completed :
 Cell 02 - Address: 48:F8:B3:4B:42:E7
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=62/70  Signal level=-48 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"<<my-essid-here>>"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000944fee48a3
                    Extra: Last beacon: 11088ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 001061745F6C6173745F696E5F7761796E65
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0104
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A7C181BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601081500000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD760050F204104A0001101044000102103B00010310470010CCEA59F5F99418868D2D108CC1AC86D1102100074C696E6B7379731023000545313230301024000776322E302E30361042000234321054000800060050F2040001101100054531323030100800022688103C0001011049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180207F02C0000
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
```

Result: I get no wireless. I've tried rebooting, it appears its properly grabbing my `essid` from `/etc/network/interfaces`

What is going wrong here? Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: IIRC you need to use `wpa-ssid` and `wpa-psk` (rather than `wireless-essid` and `wireless-psk`) for wpa connections

Comment: Is that for connections via command line in /etc/network/interfaces connections?

Comment: Also, that seems to fail my /etc/network/connection file - it no longer autoloads the connection to my predefined wifi network

Comment: wpa-ssid and wpa-psk; not wireless. wireless-ssid implies WEP; you are using WPA.